# MKLocalSearch on Swift init() doesn't work

Tags: swift, mklocalsearch

i am trying to use MKLocalSearch Api in Swift. But I can't get it to work. The error is coming from

```
var search:MKLocalSearch = MKLocalSearch.init(request)
```

I read the documentation, and it state the method name is init(request:) I am not sure what i did wrong. please advice. :)

```
var request = MKLocalSearchRequest()
        request.naturalLanguageQuery = searchTextFiled.text
        println(searchTextFiled.text)
        request.region = self.mapView.region //need to define region later
        var search:MKLocalSearch = MKLocalSearch.init(request)
        search.startWithCompletionHandler {
            (response:MKLocalSearchResponse!, error:NSError!) in
            if !error {
                var placemarks:NSMutableArray = NSMutableArray()
                for item in response.mapItems {
                    placemarks.addObject(placemarks)
                }
                self.mapView.removeAnnotations(self.mapView.annotations)
                self.mapView.showAnnotations(placemarks, animated: true)
            } else {

            }
        }
```

Comment: By the way, `placemarks.addObject(placemarks)` looks wrong.  Try `placemarks.addObject((item as MKMapItem).placemark)`.

Comment: Thanks. That could save me a lot of time! do you know how I should init the MKLocalSearch?

Comment: I think it should be `var search:MKLocalSearch = MKLocalSearch(request: request)` or just `var search = MKLocalSearch(request: request)` because Swift can infer the type.  The second "request" is your variable.

Comment: thank you so much! it finally works!

Answer (score 0):

Change this line:

```
var search:MKLocalSearch = MKLocalSearch.init(request)
```

To:

```
var search:MKLocalSearch = MKLocalSearch.init(request: request)
```

It's made a little confusing by the naming involved in this case - the first part, `request:` is a label that tells Swift which init function to call - in this case, it's mapping back to the Objective-C `initWithRequest:` method.

The second part, `request` is your `MKLocalSearchRequest` variable that you're passing to the init function. So the Objective-C equivalent is this:

```
MKLocalSearch *search = [[MKLocalSearch alloc] initWithRequest:request];
```

There's a whole chapter titled "Initialization" in Apple's *The Swift Programming Language* book, available on the iBooks store and as a PDF [here](http://techietake.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/06/the-swift-rogramming-language.pdf), albeit with worse (bordering on terrible) formatting in the PDF.

Comment: It still throws an error saying "Expected member name or constructor call after type name" after I changed to yours.

Answer (score 0):

That's incorrect syntax for init. They're implied by Swift, so you'd use

```
var x = MKLocalSearch(request: request)
```

*not*

```
var x = MKLocalSearch.init(request)
```